# Ionic: Alertbox popping up twice

Tags: alert, ionic-framework, box

I'm creating an Ionic mobile application.

I'm trying to display an alert popup box when my function fails to load a http.get request.

Initially the alert popup box was popping up 3 times. So i added a variable called `popupShow = false` and put the alert box inside a `if(!popupShow)` statement and called `popupShow = true` once the alertbox as been excuted. Now the alertbox pops up twice. I'm unsure why it is doing this.

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  $http.get('')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    })

    .error(function() {
    if(!popupShow){
      $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Internet Connectivity',
          template: 'Some features will be limited'
        })
      popupShow = true;
    }
      $ionicLoading.hide()
      if(window.localStorage.getItem("data") !== undefined) {
        $scope.data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
      }
    })

    .then(function() {
      $ionicLoading.hide()
    });
  }

  $scope.doRefresh();

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.infiniteLimit += 1;
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  }, 1000;

  $scope.moreDataCanBeLoaded = function() {
    return $scope.data.length > $scope.infiniteLimit;
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you verify how many HTTP calls are being made for each appearance of the popup? Just want to make sure something isn't calling doRefresh() more than once.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now why i'm getting two. Yes, i've got another doRefresh(). I'll edit the question to provide all my javascript code.

Comment: I understand the problem but how would i re-add it without it popping up twice. Do i need to create a new function? I guess my solution would be is to check the users internet connection instead of doing it the way i have above.

Comment: You need to make sure the controller isn't getting called twice. New Angular devs sometimes put the controller both in the routing (i.e., `app.js`) AND in the HTML (i.e., `ng-controller=`). Make sure it only appears once.

Comment: Thank you. Yep, i did put the controller in two places.